# How to use database with CDN to improve peformance

Tags: php, database, cdn, jwplayer

I have question something similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314579/how-does-a-cdn-access-database), I am using jwplayer for playing my videos. I have saved my videos in CDN. Due to some requirements, I  have to save my subtitle first in cdn and then save both video file url and associated subtitle urls [eng, chinese, japanese etc] in DB.

When I make a Ajax call to retrieve the data in my JS file from PHP file. It is taking more time and it is causing performance issue.

I was wondering if there is any DB option in CDN, so that instead of saving those detail in my db I can directly save this info (associated subtitles of one video file) in CDN. since retrieving from CDN is much faster it will surely improve the performance.

Comment: The answer to this will depend on what CDN you are using. Which one is it?

Comment: I am not sure i understand the question but i am using cloudfront cdn

Comment: @duskwuff : does it answer your question or you are asking something else?

Comment: Not if you can do this with CF. Looking on google for using cf with a database does not help much.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer : So it means we dont have any thing in `CDN CF` which support this ?

Comment: Not from a quick search on Google it seems...

Comment: yea I too tried searching in google for this but could not find anything .so  I posted in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

CDNs just bring static information closer to the users, caching that information in points-of-presence (PoPs) around the globe. It is mostly done by web-servers sitting within those PoPs. So whatever you can't retrieve by `HTTP GET` will likely be a problem. For example, legacy protocol `RTMP` (also video) is supported by legacy CDNs (Level3/Akamai/EdgeCast), but not by newly formed Cloudflare/Cloudfront and so on, because it requires adds-on to web-server and clutters workflows.

Technically, any static database can be stored in a file, and the file can be cached by a CDN. But then, again, it would be your code that takes care of db->file->db metamorphosis. Therefore, if something is static, you don't really want to use database for it (to be future/CDN-proof). Subtitles are just text files, so let them be files in asset folders. I appreciate that high level architecture might be beyond your control here (due to specific ingesting system for instance), but then the answer is that you won't be able to do what you try, and resulting performance will suffer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the bucks you can look at Continuent.

http://www.continuent.com/solutions/pricing-and-services